# How do you make configuration-specific C# build events in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, build-process

In vs2008, C# build events are configuration-specific.

Looking for ideas on how to make my build event run only when doing a Release build.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the C# projects do not support anything like this that I have found.  I have had to resort to writing makefiles in certain situations to get around this.  You could also write a batch file or a simple program that accepts a parameter then call it like this from the build event:

```
custom.exe $(ConfigurationName)
```

Answer (score 6):

ok, along Brian's line, I'm doing this:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" do_something
```

and it appears to work

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 does support per-configuration build events. Check to see if you're setting build events when you have "All Configurations" selected in the project's property dialog.

Comment: For C++ projects yes it does, but not for C# projects.  A glaring oversight imho.

Comment: Thanks, have modified title, description and tags of the question.